# Custom Column GridView in WPF (mvvm)

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm

I have a list that contains columnName and its value. So this list can be different. I mean sometimes I could have several columns and have different names.

The structer is

```
public class LookupFields
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldDisplayName { get; set; }

    public bool IsCandiateKey { get; set; }
}
```

and here is how i am loading items into grid

```
    private void InitializeGrid(ListView displayPanel, List<LookupFields> items)
    {
        //GridView gv = new GridView();

        GridLookupResult.AllowsColumnReorder = true;

        var columns = items;
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewColumn col = new GridViewColumn();

            col.Header = new Binding ("[FieldName]");
            col.DisplayMemberBinding=  new Binding("[FieldDisplayName]");


            GridLookupResult.Columns.Add(col);
        }            
        displayPanel.View = GridLookupResult;
        displayPanel.DataContext = items;
        displayPanel.ItemsSource = items;
    }
```

and here is the XAML side

```
 <ListView x:Name="listItems" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllCustomLookupItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler" >
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleDoubleClick" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <!--<GridView x:Name="listItemsGrid">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding HeaderCode}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Code}" Width="150"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding HeaderDesc2}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Desc2}" Width="150" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding HeaderDesc}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Desc}" Width="350" />
                </GridView>-->
                <GridView x:Name="GridLookupResult">
                </GridView>    
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I also filled AllCustomLookupItems with items. And result is like that..

[image]

Where did I do a mistake?

**Update:** Here is the view model side that I load the list

```
 var list = proxy.LoadAll();

        foreach (var row in list)
        {

            CustomLookup cLookup = new CustomLookup();
            cLookup.Fields=new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var col in row.PropertyTable)
            {
                cLookup.Fields.Add(col.Key, col.Value);
            }           

        }



        AllCustomLookupItems = lookUpFields;// items.Select(s => s.Model).ToList();
        _candidateKey = candidateKey;
      //  AllLookupItems = items;


   public List<LookupFields> AllCustomLookupItems
    {
        get { return _allCustomLookupItems; }
        set
        {
            _allCustomLookupItems = value;
         //   SearchExecute(null);
        }
    }
```

and in the view I access this item like:

```
   var customViewModel = (LookupCustomViewModel) dc;
   var items=customViewModel.AllCustomLookupItems;
```

Comment: Please show your ViewModel. Did you remeber to set the DataContext of the View to the ViewModel?

Comment: @KamilSolecki, thank you for your answer. I added code for loading items to AllCustomLookupItems. I think its what you asked for

Comment: Hmm, does that mean you don't have a property for AllCustomLookupItems? Can you show where and how is it instantiated?

Comment: @KamilSolecki, I also added AllCustomLookupItems property.

Comment: set your header like  `col.Header = columns[i].FieldName`

Comment: @caner, it will only set the header title but the data still not be binded.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGrid` has a  `ItemsSource` property and you can bind to a `DataView` object  `ItemsSource="{Binding DataView}"`

Comment: I do not have DataGrid, I have only Gridview. I solved the problem by converting mydata to xml  but i do not like that way.

Comment: @ertan2002 What I meant to say instead of using ListView use DataGrid and bind it to a GridView object. You can create a GridView from any DataTable with DataTable.